# Классы – конструкторы и деструкторы

Tags: c++

Вопрос из теста "Классы – конструкторы и деструкторы" (www.intuit.ru)

> В какой строчке данного кода сработает заданный в нем копирующий
>   конструктор?
>
> ```
> 1 monstr::monstr(const monstr &М){
> 2 if (M.name){
> 3 name = new char [strlen(M.name) + 1];
> 4 strcpy(name, M.name);}
> 5 else name = 0;
> 6 health = M.health; ammo = M.ammo; skin = M.skin;
> 7 }
> ...
> 8 monstr Vasia (blue);
> 9 monstr Super = Vasia;
> 10 monstr *m = new monstr ("Orc");
> 11 monstr Green = *m;
> ```
>
> Ответы:
>
> 1. в шестой
> 2. в пятой
> 3. в четвертой
> 4. в одиннадцатой

Я считаю, что в восьмой, но такого варианта нет! Что вы думаете?

Comment: Ошибся, перепутал инициализацию и присваивание 11 правильный ответ. Конструктор копирования вызовется при инициализации. Получится зеленый орк.

Comment: В восьмой в случае, если blue -- тоже монстр. А если это не монстр, тогда не подходит. Смотрите ниже.

Comment: По идее, вызовется в 9-ой и в 11-ой. http://ideone.com/zJuZ0h

    monstr Super = Vasia;

-- почти то же самое, что

    monstr Super(Vasia);

@rejie: конструктор копирования -- это если из того же типа. Если `blue` -- `monstr`, то будет вызван конструктор копирования (или если `blue` наследует `monstr`, и нету более специфичного конструктора).

Comment: Получается, что в конструкции 

    monstr Super = Vasia;

оператор присваивания не вызывается?

Comment: @rejie: нет, потому что это не присваивание, это инициализация. Смотрите http://hashcode.ru/questions/194056/ (и вообще вопросы от @mzarb).

Answer (score 3):

В 9й и в 11й.

```
8 monstr Vasia (blue);  // Конструктор (decltype(blue)), может и копирования если blue это monstr.
9 monstr Super = Vasia; // Конструктор копирования (не присваивания, т.к. это инициализация)
10 monstr *m = new monstr ("Orc"); // Конструктор (const char*)
11 monstr Green = *m; // Конструктор копирования.
```